# Programmatic component rendering in Ember 2.5 using template in .hbs file

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

There's probably already an question/answer on this, but I can't seem to find it.

I have a component defined in **components/blah-component.js** and **templates/components/blah-component.hbs**.

I need to create the component programmatically and append its contents to the DOM. I am successful at doing a **.create()**, but can't seem to get the component's template loaded automatically from .hbs file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import SrField from 'frontend/components/reports/sr-field';

...

const srField = SrField.create();
const el = document.createElement('div');

srField.appendTo(el);
```

Here the html generated is just an empty div.

I can specify the template by setting the **layout** like so:

```
layout: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Blah')
```

but how do I load the template from .hbs file?

UPDATE:

I think I got it. I can import the template file into the component, and the use it as the **layout** property:

```
import FieldTemplate from 'frontend/templates/components/reports/sr-field';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    layout: FieldTemplate,
```

UPDATE 2:

I can import the template, as stated in UPDATE above, or create it in a property. Actions work fine. There's an issue though: any other components referenced in that template cannot be found:

```
 Assertion Failed: A helper named 'autoopen-modal' could not be found
```

UPDATE 3:

Marking this question as a duplicate to refer people to my other different but related question, whose solution - Ember Wormhole - can be used here.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by `create the component programmatically`. What *exactly* do you want to do? Do you have the component at compile time or not? If not, from where should the `.hbs` files content come, if yes, why not just normally use the component?

Comment: Added code snippet for general idea what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What's your reason you are doing all of this? It seems very contradictory to Ember conventions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714810/insert-ember-component-at-cursor-in-contenteditable-element/37714935?noredirect=1#comment62904049_37714935

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it possible to do it using an outer component/controller and pushing data down to it?

Comment: Just in case you're trying to dynamically load some component that is only known at run-time, are you aware of the `{{component}}` helper?  https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/defining-a-component/#toc_dynamically-rendering-a-component